# Eliminar linhas duplicadas postgresql

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, ado.net

Meu código insere dados automaticamente em um banco, fazendo com que o BD fique muito grande e, as vezes, com informações repetidas.
Para isso, desejo usar o método Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) de forma que:
- Um registro com determinado id será adicionado no banco, e a data de inserção sera guardada no campo `data_inicial`

- Enquanto esse registro for igual, o programa apenas atualizará a `data_final`
- Quando mudar algo nesse registro, a `data_final` do registro será atualizada pra data em que a mudança aconteceu e será criado outro registro com as informações que mudaram e com a `data_inicial` atualizada. Da forma representada abaixo:

> id | cidade | data_inicial | data_final
>
> 123 | São Paulo | 01/10/2016 | 03/12/2016
>
> 123 | Rio de Janeiro | 04/12/2016 | 20/01/2017
>
> 123 | Fortaleza | 21/01/2017 | 01/01/2999

obs.: a tabela terá dados de vários id's, e mais de um dado com o mesmo id.

obs2.: utilizo um código em C# para fazer a inserção no banco de dados

Comment: Adicionar constraints de integridade no banco de dados não resolve pra você evitar as replicações?

Comment: Minha ideia era implementar o Slowly Changing Dimension Type 6, que deixaria minha tabela da forma que eu apresentei na pergunta. Mas como o código insere automaticamente na tabela, e a data_final é imprevisível, eu não estou conseguindo resolver. Eu cheguei a usar unique constraint com data_inicial e id, mas não resolve por inteiro o problema de replicação de dados iguais.